# Reading Excel File in VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

How will i be able to read an excel file in vb6 when i do not have Microsoft Excel Installed on the Server.
I am trying to Add Reference of "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library" but i cannot see the object to add in the reference.
What files or dll file should i have to download to make it work.

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim xlwBook As New Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As New Excel.WorkSheet`
```

And Can i use this application when i do not have Excel installed on my system?

Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

Comment: Pop up a cmd prompt, type odbcad32.  The ones you can use are under the Drivers tab.  You can use the jet engine or ACE OLE DB as well but you may need to install the accessdatabaseengine.exe from microsoft.

Comment: i already have access database engine installed. and i can see Microsoft Excel Driver in the ODBC Administrator. but when i am trying to add that in the reference it says "can't add reference". what am i doing is correct??

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195951

This is an article that details the steps to read an excel file as if it's a database. It needs to be in a table format.

Answer (score 1):

I am using "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library" (Office 2010) and it points straight to the Excel.exe

[image: VB6 References]

Office 2007+ favors .net but for vb6 i think you can make it work by installing [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw(v=vs.100).aspx)

And you may need to use create object instead. Like,

```
Public objExcel As Object 'instead of Excel.Application
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply!! The Way you mentioned DOES work fine with me even when i do not add any reference. but i was trying to make it work using "Excel.Application" by adding "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library".

Comment: what is the major difference using it as an object and directly using as an application?

Comment: When using object directly like "Excel.Application" it's called early binding. You will need the specific version of reference both in development machine and in client machine. When using CreateObject it's called late binding, the compiler won't bother about the internal structure of the assembly (intellisense wont work) the object is created dynamically with the assembly of the same name (Version is not important)

Comment: Did you try the link, [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw(v=vs.100).aspx) it have both 12 & 14 assembly.

Comment: Yes i tried both the links, but the problem is that i do not have MS excel installed on my system. i am using openOffice.

Comment: Look like it's not possible.. Sorry.. And take a look at [this](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=11898&lngWId=1) it's a 3rd party source for managing excel.

Comment: It is possible to use Open Office through COM. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Automation_Bridge

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Excel installed you cannot use its COM Model (`Excel.Application`) or the PIAs mentioned elsewhere (which would be of no use even if you did have Excel installed).

You should do this using ODBC & ADO.

> and i can see Microsoft Excel Driver in the ODBC Administrator .. but when i am trying to add that in the reference it says "can't add reference"

You don't reference the driver, you would reference ADO (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects) specifying the driver by name in the connection string.

There are many examples of this, E.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information. i will try it from the link you provided! thanks a lot..